# I want to remove white space between first \resumeitem and second \resumeSubheadingas highlighted with black arrow

Tags: white-space

[image: Reference image]

```
\resumeSubheading
  {Lahore University of Management Sciences (LUMS)}{}
  {Undergraduate Teaching Assistant $\mid$ \textnormal{Probability}}{\textnormal{Sept. 2022 -- Dec. 2022}}
  \resumeItemListStart
    \resumeItem{Crafted comprehensive problem sets, graded quizzes, facilitated engaging tutorial sessions, and held biweekly office hours to address student queries and enhance understanding.}
  \resumeItemListEnd
\resumeSubheading
  {}{}{Undergraduate Teaching Assistant $\mid$ \textnormal{Calculus}}{\textnormal{Jan. 2023 -- May 2023}}
  \resumeItemListStart
    \resumeItem{Created reference solutions to all course content in addition to teaching recitations and holding office hours weekly.}
  \resumeItemListEnd

  \resumeSubHeadingListEnd
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide compileable code.

This code will produce the desired result.

[image: a]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}

%-*****************************************************  added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}
\setlist{nosep}

\titleformat{\section}{\scshape\raggedright\large}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}\titlerule \vspace{-5pt}]

\newcommand{\resumeItem}[1]{\item\small{#1}}

\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{%
    \item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.99\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r@{}}
        \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
        \textit{\small#3} & \textit{\small #4}\\        
    \end{tabular*}%
}

\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{\textbullet}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{}

\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListEnd}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListStart}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListEnd}{\end{itemize}\vspace{-3ex}} % added vspace here <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
%-*****************************************************

\begin{document}

\section{Experience}
\resumeSubHeadingListStart
    \resumeSubheading
    {Lahore University of Management Sciences (LUMS)}{}
    {Undergraduate Teaching Assistant $\mid$ \textnormal{Probability}}{\textnormal{Sept. 2022 -- Dec. 2022}}
        \resumeItemListStart
            \resumeItem{Crafted comprehensive problem sets, graded quizzes, facilitated engaging tutorial sessions, and held biweekly office hours to address student queries and enhance understanding.}
        \resumeItemListEnd
    \resumeSubheading
    {}{}{Undergraduate Teaching Assistant $\mid$ \textnormal{Calculus}}{\textnormal{Jan. 2023 -- May 2023}}
        \resumeItemListStart
            \resumeItem{Created reference solutions to all course content in addition to teaching recitations and holding office hours weekly.}
        \resumeItemListEnd

\resumeSubHeadingListEnd
    
\end{document}
```